# Processing Google Forms Data Using Transpose, Sort, and Concatenate in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

My students will complete a strengths assessment via Google Forms. For every submission, I need to collapse their responses into category totals, sort those category values from high to low score, and maintain a way to label the values so I know which category it is (mixed numbers and text). In the end, the students will receive an email that shows their scores processed into categories ranked high to low with a category description. Example results data in email:

25 Judgment/Critical Thinking: You are analytical; you examine things from all sides; you do not jump to conclusions, but instead attempt to weigh all the evidence when making decisions.

20 Kindness: You do good things for people; you help and care for others; you are generous and giving; you are compassionate.

I have gotten the spreadsheet to work, but the results are not accurately sorted by number because Google reads mixed numbers and text as all text. [You can see the sorting problem starting in column KE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11OgZDbFn1qExJ2Yv2KeUSo3wWmAnxj2aLtwnbqfeUZU/edit?usp=sharing).

I was also able to corrrectly accomplish the sort by first using transpose/sort/transpose and then concatenating the results. However, that returns Row 2's results into Rows 2 and 3. When the next person submits their response, it won't work. [This is that version](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/182SYQmHMhuEOAmcoiQp8MvWmU5tTs90GttMZqBfNsbA/edit?usp=sharing). If you go to column JG you will see the problem.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

*Try this formula in `Cell_JG1` of [your sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/182SYQmHMhuEOAmcoiQp8MvWmU5tTs90GttMZqBfNsbA/edit#gid=627513588)*

```js
=ifna(vstack(,byrow(indirect("II2:JF"),lambda(Σ,index(if(sum(Σ)=0,,torow(choosecols(sort(transpose({Σ&" - "&II1:JF1;Σ}),2,),1))))))))
```

- *the formula expands downwards automatically; so do not drag it down and make sure the range `JG:KD` is void of any data so that the formula expands freely*

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you. My only issue now is that the emailing extension I use (AutoCrat) doesn't like empty boxes in row 1, so I need to figure out how to add a label.

Comment: replace this part of the formula `=ifna(vstack(,` with `=ifna(vstack([TITLES],` OR totally remove the `=ifna(vstack(,` part and just use the `byrow(formula)` from row2 onwards; that would be *Cell_JG2*